# Action show is called when it shouldn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm developing an application on Ruby on Rails, and I'm putting links to actions that display different views with translations. The thing is when I go to that page, For some reason the action "show" is called and I get a route error.

I've evend moved the route outside of the resources module that was in, but still fails.

Any idea how to solve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We can't possibly help you without seeing some relevant code.

Comment: Specifically, show us the code that generates the bad URL, and the entirety of your routes.rb.

Comment: Sorry for not posting the code, but i figured it out. It was a link in the view I was trying to access. I've seen it and changed, works fine now. Thanks for the replys, next time I'll post some code ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try couple things,

rake routes -> verify the path variable you are using is correct
check the HTML code to verify if the link_to seems right
check the server log when you hit that link, see what is going through

Comment: Actually, the routes were okay, It was a link in the view that had the wrong. It's solved now, but took me a while to figure it out. Anyway, thanks for the reply, I appreciate the feedback.